# forloop for getting object

Tags: php, object, for-loop

I have below PHP forloop, $review is object having values of 'avail_1', 'avail_2', 'avail_2' upto avail_40

```
$review_array_count = array();

for ($i=1; $i <= 4 ; $i++) {
    if(is_object($review) && $review->avail_.$i == 'yes')
    {
     array_push($review_array_count, '1');
    }
}
echo count($review_array_count);
```

I am counting how many avail_x having value of 'yes', so i am doing forloop upto 40, then pushing 1 to array and counting array.

How can i use object value as avail_.$i? This does not working.

Thanks,

Comment: try it with `$review->{'avail_'.$i}`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta, thanks it is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want to count how many avail_x having value of "yes" right?

```
$count = 0;

foreach (get_object_vars($reviews) as $key => $value) {
    if($value == 'yes'){
        $count++;
    }
}

var_dump($count);
```

Maybe this can help.

Comment: This is also a good option, i just added if(is_object($review)) to evaluate foreach only if there is object!

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 4 ; $i++) {
$testValObj = 'avail_'.$i;
$mainVal=$review->$testValObj;
    if(is_object($review) && $mainVal == 'yes')
    {
     array_push($review_array_count, '1');
    }
}
echo count($review_array_count);
```